# How to disable docker cache while building an image in VSTS build?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Im running a VSTS build which contains a docker build task. I pass --no-cache argument in the  build args field. Unfortunately, durring the build I receive a message that this arg was ignored. Did anyone had the same problem?

Comment: can you post your `docker build` command?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a solution. Issue request was closed https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4539

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of it is that, the docker build task add `--no-cache` argument after `--build-arg`, that can’t be consumed.

The workaround is that you can add additional arguments, such as `test=test --no-cache` (the warning will be [test] were not consumed.

On the other hand, you also can call docker build command through **Command Line** task.

Answer (score 0):

adding `--no-cache` did not work for me

I added a marker in the Dockerfile before the `COPY` statement I did not want to be cached

```
FROM microsoft/azure-functions-dotnet-core2.0:2.0-nanoserver-1803

ARG CACHEBUSTER=0
COPY ./FunctionApp/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/Publish /approot
```

and then placed a `RegEx Replace` task before the `docker build` task and replace *ARG CACHEBUSTER=0* with something unique e.g. *ARG CACHEBUSTER=$(Build.BuildNumber)*

Answer (score 0):

Using "azure-pipelines.yml" in the Azure Build Pipelines fixes this problem:

```
script: docker build -t $(dockerId)/$(imageName) .  # add options to this command to meet your needs
```

[Build, test, and push Docker container apps in Azure Pipelines - Build an image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-an-image)

Example:

```
pool:
 name: MarkusMeyer
 demands:
 - node.js
 - Agent.OSVersion -equals 10.0.17134

variables:
  imageName: 'your-container-image-name:$(build.buildId)'

steps:
 - script: docker build --no-cache -f Dockerfile -t $(imageName) .
displayName: 'docker build'
```